# I want to play custom sound notifications in Android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val existingChannel = notificationManager.getNotificationChannel(id)
        if (existingChannel != null) {
            notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(id)
        }
        val channel = NotificationChannel(id, name, importance)

        channel.description = description
        channel.enableLights(true)
        channel.setShowBadge(true)
        channel.setBypassDnd(dnd)
        channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
        channel.lightColor = R.color.cornflower_blue_dark
        channel.enableVibration(true)
        channel.setSound(path,
            AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_NOTIFICATION_EVENT)
                .build()
        )
        notificationManager?.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
```

I want to play custom sound notifications in Android. I have mentioned that in notification channel. But setSound is not working.
When the app is in background it wont call onMessageReceived(). 
And the channel.setSound() is also not working.
I want to have App Provided Sound for notifications.